# MaskEdit overwriting last character on enter

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, masking

There is a simple cxMaskEdit, having standard mask: '## ### ###;1; '.
Also, the AutoSelect is False.

All good, but when I return to the cxMaskEdit using cxMaskEdit.SetFocus, it changes the last character from cxMaskEdit.

For example: 
12 141 141 is becoming 12 141 140 on cxMaskEdit enter (by mouse. by setFocus).

Any help with this behaviour ? 
l.e: This behaviour is given by

```
procedure TForm1.cxMaskEdit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (cxMaskEdit1.CursorPos = 10) then
    if ((Key > 48) and (Key < 58)) or ((Key > 95) and (Key < 106)) then
    begin
      cxMaskEdit2.SetFocus;
      // cxMaskEdit2.SelStart := 0;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Any events on this MaskEdit? If you just open a new project, drag a cxMaskEdit on the form and sets its mask, does it show the same behaviour? Add a second edit to the form to be able to change focus.

Comment: As event, only on keypressdown. will check tomorrow on a fresh project.

Comment: @GabrielF: I managed to reproduce the behaviour on a fresh project, by using the code I added to the question.

Comment: Try to change the `cxMaskEdit2.SetFocus;` to `Perform(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 0, 0);` to see if this still happens. This message makes the focus jump to the next control in TabOrder list.

Comment: Wait... how is KeyDown event interfering in mouse click focus?

Comment: Just rememberd, that the cxMaskedit.Properties.AutoSelect = False;  I do not know how KeyDown interefering with the mouse enter.

Comment: Is still happening with Perform(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, 0, 0); instead of cxMaskEdit2.SetFocus;

Comment: I believe you'll have to debug the cxMaskEdit or ask the developer... this sounds like a bug in the component to me. I can't reproduce with standard TMaskEdit.

Comment: This is something you'll have to debug. I'd suggest you check at the DevExpress forums (where they have excellent support, BTW) to see if this is an issue that's occurred before, and ask there if it hasn't.

Comment: Temporary solved by using TMaskEdit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using Selection Start and Length.

```
  if ((MaskEdit1.SelStart = 9) and (((47 < Key) and (Key < 58)) or (95 < Key)
    and (Key < 106))) then
  begin
    MaskEdit2.SetFocus;
    MaskEdit2.SelStart := 0;
    MaskEdit2.SelLength := 1;
  end;
```